# Why "write" function doesn't work at first time?

Tags: c#, .net

At result write function doesn't work for "8", but it writes 7,6,5,... respectively. when I trace code , I can't find anything wrong...(code must draw a chess board with numbers)

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h");
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.Write(" ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗\n");
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        for (int i = 7; i > -1;i--)
        {
            Console.Write((i + 1).ToString());//Problem is here
            for (int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
                Console.Write("║");
                if(i%2!=0)
                {
                    if(j%2==0)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    }
                }
                Console.Write(" "+ch[i,j].ToString()+" ");
            }
            Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            Console.Write("║\n");
            if(i!=0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ╠═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╬═══╣");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝");
            }
        }
```

Comment: For 1  for(int i = 7; i > -1;i--) here loop 7 to 0
        
For 2  for(int j=0;j<8;j++) here loop 0 to 7 because j<8 
if j<=8 then it execute 0 to 8

Comment: you sure it's not only that you don't see it (Blue background and foreground on first call)?

Comment: You killed me Carsten.. :)) It's been 2 hour I couldn't find it... Thank You So much...

Comment: np ... btw: you cann accept Biris answer - I don't mind

Comment: @CarstenKönig: I can delete my answer. I debugged it, wrote the answer, and realized that you already made a comment.

Comment: But I first saw Carsten's comment

Comment: Problem solved, this is the point. :-)

Comment: @Biri - no why should you - it was fine and the OP can mark the question as answerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working, but you cannot see it.

Try

```
Console.Write(" ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗\n");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
```